# Check if cell contains numbers in Google Spreadsheet using RegExMatch

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I want to check if specific cell contain only numbers.
I know I should use `RegExMatch` but I get an error.
This is what I wrote : `=if(RegExMatch(H2,[0-9]),"a","b")`
I want it to say : write 'a' if H2 contains only numbers, 'b' otherwise.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(H2,"A","B"))
```

or

```
=if(isna(REGEXEXTRACT(text(H2,"#"),"\d+")),"b","a")
```

One reason your match isn't working also - is that it in interpreting your numbers as text. the is number function is a bit more consistent, but if you really need to use regex, then you can see in the second formula where im making sure the that source text is matching against a string.

Answer (score 2):

Your formula is right, simple you forget the double quotes at regexmatch function's regular_expression .
This is the right formula: `=if(RegExMatch(B20,"[0-9]"),"a","b")`

Answer (score -1):

```
 =REGEXREPLACE(“text”,”regex”,”replacement”)
```

It spits out the entire content but with the regular expression matched content replaced. `=REGEXREPLACE(A2,[0-9],"a")
=REGEXREPLACE(A2,![0-9],"b")`//not sure about not sign.

will fill a cell with the same text as A2, but with the 0-9 becoming an a!